# Strategy for writing to parent entity as well when storing child entities on a JPA schema with TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

in parent class allow to treat child entities as tables with the same information as parent plus some attributes. That's fine for me when reading (http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-concrete-class-annotation-xml-mapping/).

But I'd like that in case I store a child entity (currently it only fills the child table), the parent table gets updated as well with the insertion of the shared part.

Is that possible to configure, or do I need to explicitly perform `childRepo.save(child)` plus `parentRepo.save(child)` in a transaction at any given write operation?

It would be in a way a mix from TABLE_PER_CLASS and JOINED strategies. JOINED stores shared info in parent, while extra attributes in child; whereas TABLE_PER_CLASS stores everything in child. I want child tables with all information whilst parent table gets synchronizedly all the shared info as well.

Comment: What is `childRepo`?

Comment: What's a "repository"? If you mean a Spring Data repository, that's a major component that you need to include in your question. And you *never* have to cast a subclass to its superclass in order to pass it to a method accepting the superclass.

Comment: 1.Yes, sorry, Spring Data's JPA Repostory. 2.That's why I hate that workaround and I am trying to fin a neater solution

Comment: Did you ever just try writing `animalRepo.save(dog)`? I've used it without problem.

Comment: ahh sorry now i understand you. My bad. Stupid error, forget about it :p

Comment: childRepo is the repository of the child entity, as in DogRepository, CatRepository, AnimalRepository (parent). In order to store a Cat so it copies inherited part to parent, I have to do dogRepo.save(dog) + animalRepo.save(dog)

Comment: "I have to"--what *exactly* happens if you don't?

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 inheritance strategies : SINGLE_TABLE,JOINED, and TABLE_PER_CLASS. 
-TABLE_PER_CLASS : will map each entity to a table 
-SINGLE_TABLE : the parent entity and the children will be mapped to only one table(in DB you get only one table for the whole inheritance hierarchy).
-JOINED : this is the one you need, the shared attributes will be persisted in the parent table, and the child relative attributes will be persisted in the child table

Comment: Those are the strategies defined by JPA, for any other needed behavior you need to implement it your self, you can use SINGLE_Table + parentRepo.save((Parent) child)

Comment: JOINED is missing one of my needs which is storing inherited attributes of child entity on child table as well

Comment: I meant it's the nearest one to your needs, if you want to stick to the JPA defined strategies, other wise you need to add some implantation to fulfill your needs. the solution you mentioned is fine, you can also use a DB trigger or JPA listeners (listener on child entity creation which will perform a persist in the parent entity)

Answer (score 0):

Adding into the 3 inheritance strategies : SINGLE_TABLE, TABLE_PER_CLASS and JOINED.
Talking about insert, table_per_class has separate insert queries on same table but different discriminator value. Table will have nulls as well for each alternate column, the discriminator has been set for. Select will also be separate. If union sub class is used, then a single select query with union.
In Joined strategy, two inserts each for parent and child table. Select is done with parent table left outer join with child table.

So if you want to use table_per_class, you might use either union per subclass with generator class as assigned and polymorphism value as implicit or joined-sub-class.